# Obscure SOAP Bug (?) in PHP: Timeout generates an internal Error (500)

Tags: php, soap, timeout

I'm accessing a remote SOAP Service that tends to be reacting very slow from time to time (we're talking about more than 10 seconds here).
System is PHP Version 5.3.1, running on Windows Server 2003.

My client is set up like this:

```
new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => true, "exceptions" => true, "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH, "connection_timeout"=>5000));
```

Now when I'm shooting a request that takes more than about 10 seconds, the following happens: I get the late but correct response from the service, together with a 200 header (taken from SoapClient::__getLastResponse)

```
Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Via: 1.1 XXX Connection: Keep-Alive Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 430 Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 16:03:15 GMT Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

But as the SOAP result, I get a SoapFault:

```
fault:
  code: 500
  message: An internal error occurred. Please contact our support.
```

I've tried preventing this with:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5000 );
```

and setting up the SoapClient with "connection_timeout"=>5000 as seen above. Nothing helps. Any suggestions would be heavily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem while accessing a Web Service in SAP and it was not a PHP Bug but a timeout setting in the SAP Web Dispatcher.

I was fighting this for many hours trying to figure out what was wrong with PHP or the SOAP Module.

Finally, I tested in SOAP-UI and the problem was solved quickly. You should do the same with SOAP-UI. Perhaps the Webservice you are calling is depending on another remote connection that has its own timeout settings.